# Statement.executeQuery() taking too much time. Is there any way to optimise this? I am using Athena DB

Tags: java, sql, amazon-athena

`Statement.excecuteQuery()` is taking too much time, no matter what the query is.

```
athenaQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT date " +
              "FROM sid.lvmh_shareofshelf_new_cat_all_dod "+
              "where scope='PCD' and date!='' and country='" + countryName+ "' " + 
              "and rname='" + rname + "' and  top_category_lvmh='" +  top_category_lvmh + 
              "' ORDER BY date DESC";
stmt = conn.createStatement();
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
rs = stmt.executeQuery(athenaQuery);
long endTime = System.nanoTime();
System.out.println("Total time taken : "+ (endTime - startTime));
```

Time taken was 2776930359 nano seconds (2.776930359seconds)

Comment: Have you profiled it to see where the time is going to? Are you running this over external network or inside AWS?

Comment: How dynamic does your where clause values?
How many times do you execute it?
If you could add more info about what you need maybe i can help more

Answer (score 1):

I don't know internal structure of your project. I suggest few things that will help you.

- Create prepare statement instead of its compile every time. Prepare query with parameter. This is syntax level optimization you can do.
- Where clause parameter every time you want then you can create index  of it. This is database level optimization.

Than try and see is performance improve!!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But unfortunately, athena's JDBC driver is  lacking prepared statement support . So i am stuck with normal Statement object

Comment: it should have.. which version are u using

Comment: AthenaJDBC41-1.1.0.jar   I get this exception "Method Connection.preparedStatement is not yet implemented"

Answer (score 0):

I checked Athena DB driver,

https://s3.amazonaws.com/athena-downloads/drivers/AthenaJDBC41-1.1.0.jar

it has com.amazonaws.athena.jdbc.AthenaConnection class which implements java.sql.Connection interface from JDBC API. it has all overloaded methods of prepareStatement promised by JDBC.

I assume you already know benefits of using Prepared statement.

In you query in Where clause you date != ''
Is it Character data type ?

you may try

> date is not null

Comment: If you open the AthenaConnetion class , it has the below code for prepared statement    public PreparedStatement prepareStatement(String sql) throws SQLException {
        this.checkOpen();
        throw new NotImplementedException("Connection", "prepareStatement");
    }

Comment: Agree with you on above comment. can you check explain plan (Not aware if Athena provides this feature ) for respective Query?  check which clause is having a bigger cost. Did you try "date is not null"